# How do I Serialize and DeSerialize all properties to String using Mongo C# Driver's BSONClassMap

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

> > BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<X>(cm =>
> >                 {
> >                     cm.AutoMap();
> >                     cm.GetMemberMap(x => x.date).SetSerializer(new dateSerializer());
>
> ```
>         });
> ```

I am getting an error that item already  contains a key and if I remove the serializer , I get the  error ReadBsonType can only be called when state is Type and not when state is Value"

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have two problems.

1) Item already contains a key.  You need to make sure that class map registration occurs before any communication with the server occurs.  This error is likely caused by serialization taking place for X before this RegisterClassMap is called.  If you are sure this isn't true, a stack trace would be helpful.

2) Your implementation of dateSerializer is likely incorrect.  If you could post your implementation, we'd be able to help debug it.  Probably warrants a separate question.